# SQL query (GROUP BY)

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following DB outlint:
  GRADE (SID, CID, Semester, Year, Grade)
  STUDENT (SID, Name, Major)

First question is this:
        For each student, list student’s name and the number of courses successfully completed. 
        Note that a course is successfully completed if a student has earned a grade other than “W” or   “F”. Also, there may be two or more students in the database having same names.

I have the following query, but I am not sure if it is correct.  I don't have data to test against due to being required to only use the construct of the DB to answer.  Can I group by SID even if I don't specify SID in my select clause?

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(SID)
FROM STUDENT S, GRADE G
WHERE S.SID = G.SID
AND G.Grade != "W"
AND  G.Grade != "F"
GROUP BY SID, Name;
```

Comment: yes you can group by sid even if you don't select sid in select clause. use explicit join syntax. from student S join grade g on s.sid = g.sid and g.grade != 'W' and g.grade !='F'

Comment: Thank you.  Can i get rid of the Name in the group by then?  I usually do use JOIN by my prof. is really weird with it and makes us use , for some unknown reason.

Comment: yes you can as mentioned above. But imo there is bad field for count you should count(cid) courses, not students

Comment: I'm utterly impressed by your comment. I don't know why your teacher forces you to use implicit joins. The standard is ANSI SQL and ANSI sql recommends explicit joins at least since 1992.

Comment: Don't know, I had him for DB last semester, I used an inner join and he like asked a million questions on why I used inner join instead of using ,

Comment: So now you know what to answer: this is STANDARD. Oracle fully supports the explicit joins since 9i, so, no excuses anymore. In regards to your concern, you *must* group by every single element of your SELECT statement that's not an aggregate, if you go by SQL2 (1992). As of SQL3 (1999), you may use a column in a GROUP BY expression even though this column is not selected (with side effects). I'm not sure how Oracle would react to that however, but Mysql allows it

Answer (score 0):

- You have to group by SID, since your instructions clearly state that students may have the same name.
- You have to proceed with an OUTER join with grades, otherwise how to display students with 0 courses completed?
- the `COUNT` should then apply to the whole group, there's no need to specify any column in there.

Query:

```
SELECT s.SID, s.Name, COUNT(*)
FROM 
    STUDENT S 
        LEFT JOIN GRADE G ON S.SID = G.SID AND G.Grade != "W" AND  G.Grade != "F"
GROUP BY s.SID, s.Name;
```

But now, I think you omitted some information. I believe there is a course table as well, am I correct? Because as it stands, this query returns the number of compatible grades, not the number of passed courses.

Also, if you need to display the name ONLY, then you'll have to include this query in a subquery:

Query:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.cnt FROM (
    SELECT s.SID, s.Name, COUNT(*) as cnt
    FROM 
        STUDENT S 
            LEFT JOIN GRADE G ON S.SID = G.SID AND G.Grade != "W" AND  G.Grade != "F"
    GROUP BY s.SID, s.Name
) t;
```